# "This sentence doesn't cohere with an ideal set of propositions."

Tags: truth, paradox

It seems that we can reflect on various theories of truth by using their definitions of truth predicates in the formulation of liar and honest sentences. For example, imagine, "This sentence corresponds to a fact," or, "This sentence coheres with an ideal set of propositions" (i.e. those believed "at the limit of inquiry" in [coherence theories of truth](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-coherence/)). These forms of the honest sentence seem false (what fact does the first one correspond to?---and the second is free-floating, it can't be inferred from the ideal set of propositions).

But then oddly enough, too, "This sentence *doesn't* cohere with an ideal set of propositions," seems true! Or does that sentence testify against the fidelity to our concept of truth, of the coherence theory of truth, then?

What can be discerned about theories of truth, in these terms? (For versions with truth values instead of truth predicates, consider, "This sentence maps to TRUE," or, "This sentence maps to FALSE.")

Comment: What is the "ideal set of propositions"?

Comment: Idk in particular, but I'm betting the indexical function in the basic liar/honest sentences would block an inference to those sentences, from *any* set of other propositions (including a possible ideal set).

Comment: IOW, what argument would conclude in these sentences? "This sentence is true and this sentence is false; by conjunction elimination, this sentence is true/false"?

Comment: I do not even follow what they are intended to be in vaguest terms, what makes them "ideal"? Can one of them be "everything is X"? In which case "this sentence is X" is inferrable despite the indexical.

Comment: I don't believe the coherence theory of truth, granted. The SEP article mentions sets of beliefs held at the limit of inquiry or by an omniscient being as examples of the "ideal." In the former case, at least, one wonders what inquiry the honest and liar sentences answer to (seeing as, "Is this sentence true or false?" is a bizarre question, to say the least!).

Comment: by "fact" or "ideal set of propositions" to you mean something like Tim Maudlin's notion of a "boundary sentence" discussed starting on p. 52 of his book [Truth and Paradox](http://www.nyu.edu/gsas/dept/philo/courses/factual/papers/MaudlinText.pdf), where a boundary sentence is one whose truth value is supposed to be determined by "the world"? (P. 59 adds that 'one can regard the truth values of all sentences in the language as "flowing" in a step by step process from the boundary', and p. 81 says sentences whose truth values aren't determined by the boundary are 'ungrounded', neither T nor F)

Comment: [The SEP article on the coherence theory of truth](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-coherence/) starts by talking about a "specified" set of propositions and then gives accounts of specification.

Comment: I edited the post to make the meaning clearer. I am guessing "at the limit of inquiry" they are supposed to have, among other things, comprehensive semantic theory that provides ["an ideal solution to the liar paradox"](https://iep.utm.edu/par-liar/#SH2c), as IEP calls it, along with the rest of semantic paradoxes. It is conceivable that this includes assigning truth values to (some of?) 'fake' self-referential sentences. This would answer the inquiry into semantics of natural language and its comprehensive formalization. Coherence theory is uniquely accomodating for such holistic inquiries.

Comment: It's not odd at all that the negative sentences seem true since truth is always not that easy to arrive at given such any short sentence, otherwise saints will be everywhere... Also this doesn't testify against the fidelity to our concept of truth since a meaningful sentence it's rather easy at least in principle to determine the truth value of either of those 4 sentences whether you're a correspondentist or a coherentist (no self-reference in your 4 examples).